# C how count number of unique cities in a text file

Tags: c

How do i count the total number of cities that are unique?

```
For example my text file has  
New York  $255
New Jersey  $19.90
Farmvill  $300
Texas  $400
New York $17.90
```

I have tried reading the file line by line and counting the number of lines but it gave me 5 cities when there is only 4 unique cities. How should i go about this problem

Comment: Use an algorithm to find unique values?

Comment: There are many ways to get unique values from a collection, all of them easily searchable for in your favorite search engine.

Comment: Read about [hashtable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)s to get some inspiration. But we won't do your homework. Your question is **off-topic**

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Hashtable sounds like an overkill :)

Comment: You will also need to store in memory all the cities that you encounter and check to see if the city is already in the list before adding a new one.  You might want to create a counter for each item in the list and increment it each time you find a matching city

Comment: Well, I think your quest is too broad for SO as it is now. To improve it, you could post the code you have so far. Maybe then it will be a question that can be answered within the scope of SO

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you want to do :

1. Read your file line by line into an array (static or dynamically-allocated, depends on whether you know the number of lines at compilation time)
2. Remove the contents of each line between the last space and the '\n' character
3. Eventually sanitize your text (put it all lowercase, etc...)
4. Make the contents of your array unique (you'll have to think or google it, but don't worry, it's not that difficult)
5. Count the number of elements in your array

good luck ;-)

Comment: What is a container?

Comment: Well, it can be a STL vector, a list, etc...  [more reading](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/)

Answer (score 0):

Read the first city. Put it in the first entry of an array.

For every next city read, check each entry of the array if it is the same.

If not, add it to the array.

The number of entries in use of the array is the number of unique cities.

Comment: Generally, sorting and traversing will give better time complexity.

Comment: Alright thanks for the help i might just have an idea of how to do it